# Is there a way to download a file from httr::POST in R?

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to download a file which is returned from an HTTP POST call (to an API I have no control over).

I have the following curl command which does what I am trying to, submit the custom json payload in the request and downloads a file to foo.pdf.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost/requestDownloadFile' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{APPLICATION_JSON_REQUEST_PAYLOAD}
  --output foo.pdf'
```

So in R I have managed to get this working

```
system2("curl", "-X 'POST' 'http://localhost/requestDownloadFile' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{APPLICATION_JSON_REQUEST_PAYLOAD}' --output foo.pdf")
```

But the rest of the code I am adding this to uses `httr::POST` for non file downloads and looks a bit cleaner.

My question is, can I achieve the same goal with the `httr::POST` function? I don't get the contents of the file returned to me, so I somehow need to pass the equivalent of curl's `output` argument through.

Comment: See [`?httr::write_disk`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/write_disk.html) (and https://yokekeong.com/download-files-over-https-in-r-with-httr/) for an example using `httr::GET`. As long as you've already formed a `httr::POST(..)` expression, you can adapt fairly directly.

Comment: FYI, ‘httr’ has been superseded by ‘httr2’, which provides a cleaner, easier interface. I suggest switching to using ‘httr2’ for all new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @r2evans, that was exactly what I'm looking for.

To answer my question in the context of my original problem, this worked for me:

```
postResponse <- httr::POST(http://localhost/requestDownloadFile, httr::write_disk("foo.pdf", overwrite=TRUE), body = '{APPLICATION_JSON_REQUEST_PAYLOAD}',httr::content_type_json(), httr::accept("*/*"))
```